# WCF service with sensitive data to be accessed only by my silverlight control

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service, key

I have a .svc service and i want it to return data only to my silverlight control.

I was thinking of requiring a predefined key in service's functions and this key will be hard coded in silverlight control.

but i know it is possible that the silverlight control may be decompiled and then the predefined key caught.

Could you please suggest a better way to protect my service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I think that is what you need.